# Question on how to set up multiple distinct listeners with Service Weaver

Tags: go

I've been playing with Service Weaver now that it's been out for a while, and am curious how we should set up multiple listeners with it. My intention is for when we deploy the app that the handler for `web` and the handler for `api` are run separately (as an example). My code is currently as follows:

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "log"
    "sync"

    "github.com/ServiceWeaver/weaver"
    "github.com/labstack/echo/v4"
    "github.com/labstack/echo/v4/middleware"
)

type Server struct {
    weaver.Implements[weaver.Main]
    apiServer weaver.Ref[APIServer]
    webServer weaver.Ref[WebServer]
}

type APIServer interface {
    Serve(context.Context) error
}

type apiServer struct {
    weaver.Implements[APIServer]
    api weaver.Listener
}

func (a apiServer) Serve(ctx context.Context) error {
    logger := a.Logger(ctx)
    e := echo.New()
    e.Listener = a.api

    e.Use(middleware.RequestID())

    e.Use(middleware.RequestLoggerWithConfig(middleware.RequestLoggerConfig{
        LogStatus: true,
        LogURI:    true,
        LogValuesFunc: func(c echo.Context, v middleware.RequestLoggerValues) error {
            logger.Info("Request", "id", v.RequestID, "uri", v.URI, "status", v.Status, "size", v.ResponseSize)
            return nil
        },
    }))

    return e.Start("")
}

type WebServer interface {
    Serve(context.Context) error
}

type webServer struct {
    weaver.Implements[WebServer]
    web weaver.Listener
}

func (w webServer) Serve(ctx context.Context) error {
    logger := w.Logger(ctx)
    e := echo.New()
    e.Listener = w.web

    e.Use(middleware.RequestID())

    e.Use(middleware.RequestLoggerWithConfig(middleware.RequestLoggerConfig{
        LogStatus: true,
        LogURI:    true,
        LogValuesFunc: func(c echo.Context, v middleware.RequestLoggerValues) error {
            logger.Info("Request", "id", v.RequestID, "uri", v.URI, "status", v.Status, "size", v.ResponseSize)
            return nil
        },
    }))

    return e.Start("")
}

func main() {
    if err := weaver.Run(context.Background(), serve); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}

func serve(ctx context.Context, server *Server) error {
    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
    wg.Add(2)

    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        server.apiServer.Get().Serve(context.Background())
    }()

    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        server.webServer.Get().Serve(context.Background())
    }()

    wg.Wait()

    return nil
}
```

Basically, I'm just setting up two Echo servers, one for each component.

For what it's worth, here's my configuration:

```ini
[serviceweaver]
binary = "./platform"

[multi]
listeners.api = { address = "localhost:12345" }
listeners.web = { address = "localhost:54321" }

[single]
listeners.api = { address = "localhost:12345" }
listeners.web = { address = "localhost:54321" }
```

When I run it in a single process, everything seems to be working as-expected. I see log entries for web requests, indicating that things are working correctly. When I run it in deploy mode (i.e., actually doing the multiple process magic), I am only able to make 1-2 requests before I see log entries like the following and then responses don't work very often:

```
2023/09/14 21:35:51 http: proxy error: context canceled
```

It would seem that I'm doing something wrong, but it seems like this is a use case that would be supported somehow, so I'm wondering if there's a proper way to go about this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr** Service Weaver does not currently have a good way to run HTTP servers from non-main components. I recommend you move both listeners to the `Server` struct and run both HTTP servers inside the `serve` function. The HTTP servers can call methods on other components.

```golang
type Server struct {
    weaver.Implements[weaver.Main]
    api weaver.Listener
    web weaver.Listener
}
```

### Details

The `weaver multi` deployer replicates every component twice, with every replica run in its own OS process. Consider what happens when the `APIServer` component requests a network listener on port 12345. The two replicas of the `APIServer` component cannot both listen on port 12345; only one OS process can listen on the port. To resolve this, the two replicas each listen on a randomly selected port, let's say 8000 and 9000. The `weaver multi` deployer then runs an HTTP proxy on port 12345 that forwards requests to ports 8000 and 9000.

In your application, the main `Server` component is replicated twice, and the `serve` function is run twice, once on each replica. Inside of `serve`, when you call `apiServer.Get().Serve(context.Background())`, a replica of the `APIServer` is chosen at random to execute the `Serve` method. If by luck, the two method calls are sent to two different replicas, then everything should run smoothly. If, however, both method calls are sent to the same replica, then one replica of the `APIServer` is running an HTTP server, while the other is not.

In this situation, the proxy forwards half of all requests to a running HTTP server and the other half of requests to a listener that's not listening. This leads to the proxy errors you're seeing.

Finally note that things work when you run your application with `go run` or `weaver single deploy` because there is no proxying and because components are not replicated.